# Difference between 'How come I know' and 'How can I know'

Tags: differences

What is the difference between these two sentences? 
Or are they the same?

> How come I know what you study?
>
> How can I know what you study?

Comment: [How come](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how_come) means *why, why is it, for what reason or purpose*. You don't use **do** in the two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

First, the sentences are grammatically incorrect, since you must not use the **do** verb in both sentences, as @Rathony just said. The reason is that the second part of the sentence is a statement, that doesn't need **do**.

Your sentences would be then:

> 1. How come I know what you study?
> 2. How can I know what you study?

Now, back to your question.

***How come*** is another way to say ***For what reason why*** or ***Why is it***.
Considering that, your first sentence would mean:

> What is the reason why I know what you study?

You're asking the reason you know what the other person is studying.

About the second one, you're basically asking the other person:

> What is the method/way to know what you study?

Here you are asking how you're able to know what the other person is studying.

Answer (score 1):

> How come I know what you study?

This implies you know what they study, but are unclear why you know it.

> How can I know what you study?

This implies you do not know what they study, and are unclear as to how you can learn it.